# Gather job usage information on cluster

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cluster

I am running simulations on a linux cluster shared by hundreds of other users. There is a job scheduler installed on the cluster that determines who runs where, and one of the scheduler commands (`showq`) displays a list of all the active jobs, idle jobs, blocked jobs etc. I would like to process that output to determine things like the number of unique users running jobs at any one point. Here is a sample of some output from `showq -r`, which shows the running jobs:

```
active jobs------------------------
JOBID               S  PAR  EFFIC  XFACTOR  Q  USERNAME    GROUP            MHOST PROCS   REMAINING            STARTTIME 
123456              R  bas  -----    1.0    -   user_X    group_A            n1     8    4:00:00  Fri Sep 19 17:25:05
123457              R  bas  -----    1.0    -   user_Y    group_B            n2     16    4:00:00  Fri Sep 19 17:25:05  
123458              R  bas  -----    1.0    -   user_Y    group_B            n3     1    4:00:00  Fri Sep 19 17:25:05 
123459              R  bas  -----    1.0    -   user_X    group_A            n4     1    4:00:00  Fri Sep 19 17:25:05 
123460              R  bas  -----    1.0    -   user_X    group_A            n5     2    4:00:00  Fri Sep 19 17:25:05 
123461              R  bas  -----    1.0    -   user_Z    group_A            n6     4    4:00:00  Fri Sep 19 17:25:05 
......

5000 active jobs
```

Specifically, I would like to calculate:

1. The number of unique users running jobs, and how many jobs each user is running (I would also like to do the same for groups, but that will be trivial to do once you've done it with users)
2. The number of processor cores (`PROCS`) a user/group is occupying
3. The number of serial (`PROC=1`) and parallel (`PROC>1`) jobs a user/group is running

I could do this in Python rather easily, but I'd like to pull it off using some combination of `awk`/`sed` or other linux commands. Slick one-liners make me happy :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is remove the unwanted lines from the output of `showq -r`, i.e. lines that say active jobs, etc ..which can be done using `showq -r | sed '1,2d' |sed '$d'`, or you can use `grep` with a regular expression that describes part of the data row - e.g. `grep "----"` in this case may work if value of `EFFIC` is always `----`. Once you've got a file with only data rows, you use [`associative arrays in awk`](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_12.html) to do rest of the magic.

```
#!/bin/awk

{ 
  proc_count[$7] = proc_count[$7] + $10;        
  if ($10 > 1) { multi_proc[$7]++; } else { single_proc[$7]++;  }
}
END { 
  for (foo in proc_count) { print foo, proc_count[foo], multi_proc[foo], single_proc[foo] }
}
```

If you run the script above you'll note that nothing is displayed for serial processor count for `user_z`. That's because I was trying to save lines and didn't print a `0` there. I'll leave it up to you to add the error checking and prettify the output.

Comment: This is what I was looking for - many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At first store the following script and `chmod +x`  to it.suppose name it `job_processor.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk  -f
## $7 username
## $8 groupname
## $10 procs
{
if ( $10 == 1 )
    printf ("username: %s and groupname: %s are serial!\n",$7,$8);
else if  ( $10 > 1 )
    printf ("username: %s and groupname: %s are parallel!\n",$7,$8);



printf ("username: %s and groupname: %s with  procs: %d!\n",$7,$8,$10);
}
```

you have to use the following format:

```
cat jobs |./job_process.awk |sed '1,2d' |sed '$d'
```

Output is :

```
username: user_X and groupname: group_A are parallel!
username: user_X and groupname: group_A with  procs: 8!
username: user_Y and groupname: group_B are parallel!
username: user_Y and groupname: group_B with  procs: 16!
username: user_Y and groupname: group_B are serial!
username: user_Y and groupname: group_B with  procs: 1!
username: user_X and groupname: group_A are serial!
username: user_X and groupname: group_A with  procs: 1!
username: user_X and groupname: group_A are parallel!
username: user_X and groupname: group_A with  procs: 2!
username: user_Z and groupname: group_A are parallel!
username: user_Z and groupname: group_A with  procs: 4!
```

Comment: i updated to using sed.